# Post-hoc analysis of 3 sample prop.test

Tags: r, proportion, post-hoc

I am looking for the correct way of performing post-hoc analysis on the results of a 3-sample test for equality of proportions and haven't been able to find anything specific to this test.

The data I am analyzing looks like this:

```
               pos.late neut.late neg.late
    pos.early        88        12        4
    neut.early       23       112        7
    neg.early        58       150        5
```

The row names are how individuals responded in an early time period, and the column names are how they responded in a late time period. The values in each cell represent how many individuals showed that particular response over time (e.g. 88 individuals were positive in the early time period and remained positive in the late).

I performed a `prop.test()` in R for each row – here is an example for the `pos.early` row:

```
> prop.test(c(88,23,58), c(88+23+58, 88+23+58, 88+23+58))

    3-sample test for equality of proportions without
    continuity correction

data:  c(88, 23, 58) out of c(88 + 23 + 58, 88 + 23 + 58, 88 + 23 + 58)
X-squared = 56.3609, df = 2, p-value = 5.773e-13
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2    prop 3 
0.5207101 0.1360947 0.3431953
```

There is clearly a significant difference, but what post-hoc test is best used with the `prop.test()` to determine which of the `pos.early`–`pos.late`, `pos.early`–`neut.late`, `pos.early`–`neg.late` pairings are significant?

Comment: Nick, apologies if I am being obtuse, but why isn't this simply a 3 by 3 $\chi^{2}$ test with *post hoc* 2 by $\chi^{2}$ tests adjusted for multiple comparisons (and possibly for continuity corrections)?

Comment: prop.test(c(88,23,58), c(88+23+58, 88+23+58, 88+23+58)) 
is not an appropriate test for your data.  This test would be testing three independent samples to see if $p_1=p_2=p_3$.  In your case, when looking at a single column, you do not have three independent samples, you have one sample with 3 categories.  It seems you were attempting to perform a chi-square goodness of fit test to test the null hypothesis that $p_1=p_2=p_3=1/3$, but it's not clear that this is what you really wanted to do.  What is the research question you are trying to address with the hypothesis test?

Comment: @jsk Thank you for taking a look at this question and your thorough answer. I wish to determine if there is a difference in how many positive responders from the early time period (pos.early) shift to positive, negative, and neutral in the late time period. It looks like the chi-square goodness of fit might work for me - seeing my research question, do you still agree that this is the case?